# Reset Windows Default Printer after PrintDialog() and PrintDocument().Print() in C#

Tags: c#, printing

Using

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

private void Main()
{
  PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
  pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);

  PrintDialog pdi = new PrintDialog();
  pdi.Document = pd;

  // -> preventing PrintDialog from changing the default printer
  // -> BUT changing the PrintDocuments-Printer to the selected??

  if (pdi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    pd.Print();

    // -> OR reset default Printer?
  }
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    //- do the printing
    ev.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

always changes the default Windows Printer if the user selects a printer with PrintDialog:

- How can I prevent the change by PrintDialog? And how to set the selected Printer for PrintDocument

or

- Do I need to reset the default printer after printing? How?

or

- Am I'm doing something wrong (I need to develop with Net Framework 2.0)

Regards Thomas

Comment: Just don't fret about this.  When the user picks a different printer in the dialog then he's got a good reason.  You have no idea why.  But fairly likely he'll want to use the same printer again the next time he prints.  Resetting it is very likely to inconvenience the user, never do that.

Comment: Oh, Yes! You are right (I didn't expect this)... this behavior has been changed in new Windows Versions. (e.g. Windows 2000 - default printer was not changed by selecting another Printer from the Printer-Select-Dialog) - not sure if I like that!